# Wicket: dynamically arrange elements in list

Tags: wicket

I have a list of elements, defined in template as:

```
 <dl>
                <wicket:enclosure>
                    <dt><wicket:message key="numberTitle" />:</dt>
                    <dd wicket:id="objectNumber">1</dd>
                </wicket:enclosure>
...
                <wicket:enclosure>
                    <dt><wicket:message key="nameTitle" />:</dt>
                    <dd wicket:id="objectName">2</dd>
                </wicket:enclosure>
</dl>
```

I need to able to split dl into two lists, based on actual values - some text, others result in EmptyPanel or custom element which is hiding itself if empty. Example:

```
<dl>
                <wicket:enclosure>
                    <dt><wicket:message key="numberTitle" />:</dt>
                    <dd wicket:id="objectNumber">1</dd>
                </wicket:enclosure>
...
</dl>
<dl>
                <wicket:enclosure>
                    <dt><wicket:message key="nameTitle" />:</dt>
                    <dd wicket:id="objectName">2</dd>
                </wicket:enclosure>
</dl>
```

In a corresponding Java class i am able to verify, what values are added. My idea was to add handlers between each list element, like

```
 <wicket:container wicket:id="split_1">
 ...
 <wicket:container wicket:id="split_2">
```

and create an element, which would render `</dl><dl>`, then put it only where i need this split. But wicket performs validation on this and does not allow me to render that 'invalid' markup, besides that solution looks awful.

Maybe there should be a way to programmatically create two lists and then iterate across them to render?

Comment: Please add a sample snippet for the result HTML you need to produce.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that it is better to keep both lists in the markup and add your elements to the appropriate one.  Make a small Panel that holds the repeated markup you have in the `<wicket:enclosure>`.  Then the java would look something like this:

```
RepeatingView list1 = new RepeatingView("list1");
add(list1);

RepeatingView list2 = new RepeatingView("list2");
add(list2);

for (Object a : listOfItems) {
  if (shouldGoInFirstList(a))
     list1.add(new MyPanel(list1.newChildId(), a);
  else
     list2.add(new MyPanel(list2.newChildId(), a);
}
```

and the HTML is simply:

```
<dl>
   <wicket:container wicket:id="list1"></wicket:container>
</dl>
<dl>
   <wicket:container wicket:id="list2"></wicket:container>
</dl>
```